# Why casting from SomeClass<T> where T : BaseClass to SomeClass<DerivedClass : BaseClass> is not possible?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, covariance

I am trying to create a generic method that returns an instance of `IRowMapper<T>`. Here are my classes:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    protected void Person() { }

    protected void Person(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class Employer : Person
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public void Employer() { }

    public void Employer(int id, int employeeId) : base(id)
    {
        EmployeeId = employeeId;
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public int EmployerId { get; set; }

    public void Employee() { }

    public void Employee(int id, int employerId) : base(id)
    {
        EmployerId = employerId;
    }
}

public static class MapBuilder<TResult> where TResult : new()
{
    // ...
}

public interface IRowMapper<TResult>
{
    TResult MapRow(IDataRecord row);
}
```

Now what I would like to do is something like the following:

```
private IRowMapper<T> GetRowMapper<T>() where T : Person, new()
{
    var rowMapper = MapBuilder<T>.MapNoProperties()
                                    .Map(c => c.Id).ToColumn("ID");

    if (typeof (T) == typeof (Employee))
    {
        rowMapper =
            ((MapBuilder<Employee>) rowMapper).Map(c => c.EmployerId)
                                                .ToColumn("EmployerID");
    }
    else if (typeof (T) == typeof (Employer))
    {
        rowMapper =
            ((MapBuilder<Employer>) rowMapper).Map(c => c.EmployeeId)
                                                .ToColumn("EmployeeId");
    }

    return rowMapper.Build();
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Error 2 Cannot convert type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.IMapBuilderContext' to
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.MapBuilder'
>
> Error 2 Cannot convert type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.IMapBuilderContext' to
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.MapBuilder'

Why is the cast not possible?

Comment: "Generic" means that the same code works for *all* types. Having different code paths for a limited number of types indicates a problem in your design. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @dtb, you are right, it wasn't clever to use something like this. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with this library, but it looks like the return value of each method is an `IMapBuilderContext<T>` and it's written in a typical fluent style.

I think this might work for you:

```
private IRowMapper<T> GetRowMapper<T>() where T : Person, new()
{
    var rowMapper = MapBuilder<T>.MapNoProperties()
                                 .Map(c => c.Id).ToColumn("ID");

    if (typeof (T) == typeof (Employee))
    {
        rowMapper = ((IMapBuilderContextMap<Employee>)rowMapper)
            .Map(c => c.EmployerId).ToColumn("EmployerID");
    }
    else if (typeof (T) == typeof (Employer))
    {
        rowMapper = ((IMapBuilderContextMap<Employer>)rowMapper)
            .Map(c => c.EmployeeId).ToColumn("EmployeeId");
    }

    return rowMapper.Build();
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it but I'm sure it would work. I couldn't see it even when I was copying the Error code. Thanks a lot!